# sublime text 2 console shows only first line of gruntjs output

Tags: windows, build, console, sublimetext2, gruntjs

When running grunt in sublime text 2 on windows it seems as thought it only shows the first line of output. Strangely enough all tasks are completed. Adding `"shell": true` or `false` doesn't seem to have any effect. Neither does adding `cmd /c` or even `start /wait /b`.

How can I stop sublime text from eating the rest of the output?

```js
// grunt.sublime-build
{
    "cmd": ["grunt.cmd", "--no-color", "--verbose"],
    "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}",
    "selector": ["source.js", "source.less", "source.json", "source.ts"],
    "shell": true
}
```

The only output I get is:

```
Initializing
[Finished in 1.6s]
```

**Update**
This seems to be related to Sublime Text 2 issue 23: [Windows Build Panel Eats Stdout](https://github.com/uipoet/sublime-jshint/issues/23).

**Update**
There is a workaround, but it's ugly.

```js
// grunt.sublime-build
{
    "cmd": ["grunt.cmd", "--no-color", ">", "c:\\temp\\st2.txt", "&&", "type", "c:\\temp\\st2.txt"],
    "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}",
    "selector": ["source.js", "source.less", "source.json", "source.ts"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I put together a slightly more simple build script that will write and remove the temporary file in the current directory:

```
{
    "cmd": ["grunt --no-color > grunt.status & type grunt.status && del grunt.status"],
    "working_dir": "${project_path}/assets/js/src",
    "shell": true
}
```

Source here: https://gist.github.com/3951895

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues with Sublime Text, but creating a new build command for each project I worked on felt awkward. So I was happy when I found and installed the plugin [Grunt](https://github.com/tvooo/sublime-grunt/).

It didn't work on all different platforms I worked on in the start. So before I knew it, I was one of the contributors in that project. It basically gives you all the commands in your `Gruntfile` with the command `CTRL + SHIFT + P - Grunt` and all your grunt tasks are at your fingertips. We lost coffeescript based `Gruntfile` support with the latest releases, but I'm certain that it will be back soon.

It's a registered plugin, so you can install it with [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net/).